# Run exe from DBMS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dbms-scheduler

I am kind of new in DMBS_SCHEDULER and I face some problems.
I want to run an .exe
So I created a Job:

```
begin
   sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name            => 'FTREC.EXE_1',
                            job_type            => 'EXECUTABLE',
                            job_action          => 'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe',
                            start_date          => to_date(null),
                            repeat_interval     => '',
                            end_date            => to_date(null),
                            job_class           => 'IRECS_JOB_CLASS',
                            enabled             => false,
                            auto_drop           => false,
                            comments            => '');
end;
```

I have also created credentials :

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_CREDENTIAL('WWLSERVER','WWLSERVER','1234',null,null,null);
```

And I applied the credentials to my job

```
dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('FTREC.EXE_1', 'credential_name', 'WWLSERVER');
```

But when I try to run my Job I get this error:

```
EXTERNAL_LOG_ID="job_255737_183883",
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: The extended attributes are inconsistent.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credentials were not available in 10g.  There are no mentions of the word "credential" in the
[DBMS_SCHEDULER documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI).

I was able to run your code in 12c.  But running `calc.exe` created an un-killable session, I had to restart the database.  Things went much better when I used a simple .bat file for testing.

[This thread](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/557102) on the Oracle Forums has methods for running an external program on 10g.