# ORA-06550: Symbol met in place of one of the following symbols

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, asp-classic, oracle11g

I'm working on an ASP.NET/ORACLE Application, where I'm trying to export users' Tables using a procedure but I always receive an error.  I know that the error is in procedure syntax, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
public static int ExporterTable(string login, string mdp, string Nomtable)
{
    UserDAL.Connect(login, mdp);
    OracleTransaction trans = UserDAL.conn.BeginTransaction();
    //try
    //{
    //  string sQuery1 = "exp userid="+login+"/"+ mdp+ " file='C:\\dell\\" +Nomtable+".txt'";
    //  string sQuery1 = "expdp scott/tiger tables=EMP directory=DATAPUMP dumpfile=EMP.dmp logfile=expdpEMP.log";
    //  string sQuery1="exp system/manager FILE=exp_u.dmp LOG=exp_u.log OWNER=oracle
    string sQuery1 = "BEGIN exp userid:=" + login + "/" + mdp + " tables:=" + Nomtable + " file:='C:\\Dell\\" + Nomtable + ".dmp' log:='C:\\Dell\\" + Nomtable + ".log' END;";
    OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(sQuery1, UserDAL.conn);

    cmd1.Transaction = trans;
    // Exécution de la requête

    cmd1.CommandText = sQuery1;
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // On soumet la requête au serveur: tout s'est bien déroulé , la requête est exécutée
    trans.Commit();
    UserDAL.CloseConnection();
    return 1;

    //}
    //catch (Exception) { return 0; }
}
```

Here is the error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 17: PLS-00103: Symbol "USERID" met in place
>   of one of the following symbols:
>
> : =. (% @; Symbol "." was substituted for "USERID" to continue.
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 41: PLS-00103: Symbol "TABLES" met in place
>   of one of the following symbols:
>
> . (* @% & = - +  At in is mod remainder not rem     <> or! = or ~ => = <= <> and or like LIKE2    Between like4
>   likec | | member submu ORA-06550: line 1, column 59: PLS-00103: Symbol
>   "FILE" met in place of one of the following symbols:
>
> . (* @% & = - +  At in is mod remainder not rem     <> or! = or ~ => = <= <> and or like LIKE2    Between like4
>   likec | | multiset membe

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have a lot of issues going on here:

There is no colon ":" used in EXP parameter assignment, just PARAMETER=value.  Read the [EXP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082)

EXP is not an oracle PL/SQL or SQL command.  It it a command-line executable.  You cannot just call it as an anonymous PL/SQL block.  You need to launch it from a shell/command script of some sorts.

You can use the dbms_scheduler package to schedule a task to run on the server (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710126/run-exe-from-dbms-scheduler) how to do that),  or use [DBMS_DATAPUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_datpmp.htm#BABHBEHH) to export data.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear OldProgrammer i will try to Use DATAPUMP